# r predict glm score based on only partial records

Tags: r, glm

I have a glm based on data A and I'd like to score data B to do validation, but some records in B have missing data.

Instead of these ending up without a score (na.omit) or being removed (na.exclude) I'd like them to end up with an outputted prediction that uses the model to determine a value based only on the data with values.

A reproducible example...

```
data(mtcars)
model<-glm(mpg~.,data=mtcars)
mtcarsNA<-mtcars
NAins <-  NAinsert <- function(df, prop = .1){
  n <- nrow(df)
  m <- ncol(df)
  num.to.na <- ceiling(prop*n*m)
  id <- sample(0:(m*n-1), num.to.na, replace = FALSE)
  rows <- id %/% m + 1
  cols <- id %% m + 1
  sapply(seq(num.to.na), function(x){
    df[rows[x], cols[x]] <<- NA
  }
  )
  return(df)
}
mtcarsNA<-NAins(mtcarsNA,.4)
mtcarsNA$mpg<-mtcars$mpg
predict(model,newdata=mtcarsNA,type="response")
```

Where I need the last line to return a result (non-NA) for all records.  Can you point me in the direction of the code needed?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do imputation.  I think there might be packages called (??) `mi`/`mice`, or try `library("sos"); findFn("imputation")`

Comment: Will take a look now, but to be clear I don't want to impute the missing values in the predictors and then get a score - I want to use only available data and use only the relevant coefficients, which could result in a lower score but fits the requirements I've been given

Comment: So do you want to fill in zeros for the missing data?  If `y=a+b*x1+c*x2` and `x2` is missing, what do you want `y-hat` to be? `a+b*x1` or something else?  I would normally suggest `y=a+b*x1+c*x2bar` where `x2bar` is the mean of `x2` across non-missing cases, which is a (**VERY**) crude form of imputation ...

Comment: it should be `a+b*x1`

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You should replace $x_2$ with $\bar{x}_2$. Mean is the probabilistically weighted estimate of $x_2$. But since you actually have a generalized linear model, you really need to do the following. Suppose your prediction function is $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$. Then the correct prediction with missing values $x_{n_1}, x_{n_2},\ldots x_{n_k}$ is $\int \ldots \int f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) p(x_{n_1}, \ldots , x_{n_k}) dx_{n_1}\ldots dx{n_k}$, where $p$ is the probability density. Replace integral with sum and density with probability for discrete outcomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the conversation in the comments, you want to replace `NA` values with zero before predicting.  This seems dangerous/dubious to me -- use at your own risk.

```
naZero <- function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x }
mtcarszero <- lapply(mtcarsNA,naZero)
predict(model,newdata=mtcarszero,type="response")
```

should be what you want.

For categorical variables, if you are using default treatment contrasts, then I think the consistent thing to do is something like this:

```
naZero <- function(x) { if (is.numeric(x)) {
                            repVal <- 0
                        } else {
                           if (is.factor(x)) {
                               repVal <- levels(x)[1]
                           } else stop("uh-oh")
                        }
                        x[is.na(x)] <- repVal
                        x }
```

Comment: I might phrase my similar concern by saying that this is in no way "ignoring" or "not using" the missing values. You're including them but assuming they are all 0. Assuming all missing values have a value of pi wouldn't be ignoring them either.

Comment: Great idea - elegantly simple.  I have to work on it a bit for categorical variables but the concept is sound - thank you very much.